# Unable to read functions from my other solidity contract files

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat

I am following the Crypto Zombies learning project. It is a multipage project, where one file imports from the other and i am attempting to test it locally using hardhat. Now my issue is when i try to test my

```
await contractInstance.transferFrom(alice, bob, id, {from: alice});
```

function, i get this error

> TypeError: contractInstance.transferFrom is not a function

I require the first (entry) contract in the project like this

```
const ZombieFactory = artifacts.require("ZombieFactory");
```

And the function i need to test on that file works. The functions on all the other files that form the project fails and i dont know why. On the Crypto zombies website, they only require that entry ZombieFactory file also.

I pushed the entire project structure on github here

[Git hub link](https://github.com/avwunufe/CryptoZombies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `transferFrom` function in your `ZombieFactory.sol` contract, there are only two public / external functions which are:

```
function createRandomZombie(string memory _name) public;

function kill() public;
```

You should deploy `ZombieOwnership.sol` so your contract will have all of the functions, including `transferFrom`

[image: ZombieInheritence]

Comment: Not meaning to go back and forth but i literally followed the tutorial step by step, and here is their finished project. https://cryptozombies.io/en/lesson/5/chapter/13. Their ZombieFactory only inherits directly from Ownable. I am trying to follow same project structure. The order of their inheritance is ZombieFactory > ZombieFeeding > ZombieHelper > ZombieAttack > ZombieOwnership

Comment: Ok, I checked the whole project, you deploy your contract partially, that's why you don't have all the functions, I edited my response and added a schematic hoping that it will be more comprehensible

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realized that as soon as I listed the order of inheritance in my last reply and it works now!